# Regex to match string that does not have a preceding string

Tags: python, regex

I'm using python to parse some files with multiple lines and perform regex using `re.findall()`.

I'm trying to match lines with the string "bar" as long as the string "no foo " is NOT in front of "bar". In other words - match any "bar" but do not match "no foo bar". If "bar" appears outside of the "no foo bar" then it should match.

Input:

```
1. candy bar 1
2. no bar stool
3. no foo bar here
4. foo barred
5. still no foo bar.
6. foo bar!
7. foobar!
8. tricky no foo bar but has bar again
```

Desired Output:

```
1. candy bar 1
2. no bar stool
4. foo barred
6. foo bar!
7. foobar!
8. tricky no foo bar but has bar again
```

This is similar to the expression I have been trying but have not had any success:

```
(^|[^no foo ])bar
```

Code:

```
patterns = ["XXX", "(^|[^no foo ])bar"]
joinedpatterns = "|".join(patterns)
for line in lines:
   for match in re.findall(joinedpatterns, line):
       print 'found "%s"' % str(match)
```

Comment: Looks like an exercise from first year in university or something

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying to achieve is called a negative look-behind:

```
for line in lines:
    for match in re.findall('(?<!no foo )bar', line):
        print('found "%s"' % str(line))
```

Comment: This prints "no foo bar foo bar foo bar" twice eventhough the line is unique.